# Rename regulation tag to gene-regulation?

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

I was just retagging [How do nuclear receptors locate each other to form a DNA loop](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/2181/how-do-nuclear-receptors-locate-each-other-to-form-a-dna-loop) and wanted to add [gene-regulation](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gene-regulation). That didn't exist, but I found [regulation](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regulation). That sounds a bit too generalised to me (regulation of enzymes/genes/acidity/potential/...?).

So I was wondering: A) is there a different way than asking on meta to propose renaming a tag or adding a synonym? B) Should that one be renamed to [gene-regulation](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gene-regulation) because that's what it is at the moment? Otherwise I would make the tag wiki for it something like "Questions about regulation mechanisms such as gene regulation,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were only two such tags, I changed them both.

I agree that [regulation](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regulation) is too general: it even says on [create tags](https://biology.stackexchange.com/privileges/create-tags) permissions page that meta tags (tags which can't stand on their own) aren't allowed.

You already have the rep to create tags, just re-tag your question [gene-regulation](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gene-regulation). Creating a tag synonym from general --> specific seems dangerous, though, and since this one was only used on two questions, I don't think we need to create a synonym.

Comment: But in order to propse creating a tag synonym / renaming / deleting a tag, asking on meta *is* the only way unless I have the privilege?

Comment: @Armatus I believe that only moderators can rename or delete a tag.  The process for suggesting synonyms is shown on the privileges page :)

Comment: @RoryM Thanks for the hint, I didn't see that! I was looking in FAQ and on the tag pages themselves. :)

Comment: @Armatus, I'm of the wikipedia philosophy of breaking things first and asking for permission later. You earned your reputation.

Comment: @bobthejoe Rocking the internet, Caesar style!